# Advice on creating large maps with complex physic bodies

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a simple game where you need to make it to the end of the course without touching any of the sides. I'm just having trouble figuring out the best way to do this.

Should I string together a bunch of images/nodes (see below) where the path to travel on is transparent and then create a physics body using `SKPhysicsBody(... alphaThreshold: 0.05 ...)` so that anything that isn't transparent has a physics body? Or is a node with 2 non joining physic bodies not possible?

[image]

Or can I use one giant picture without the need to string them?

All advice is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Switch from a screen size chunk to another as the game character moves.

Comment: In the design you provided, I would make 1 physics body for the entire level providing that the path never changes, but inverse of your path.  Basically the shaded area should represent the physics body,  look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520379-bodywithpolygonfrompath for how to do the physics body and https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor to make your life a lot easier